# Reducing an array of rows to an aggregate summed-up row using Underscore or Lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of rows that looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    metric1: 50,
    metric2: 60
  },
  {
    metric1: 100,
    metric2: 120;
  }
]
```

and I'd like to reduce this to a single row that looks like this:

```
{
  metric1: 150,
  metric2: 180
}
```

So far I have a pretty longhand approach:

```
_.reduce(function(row, aggregate) {
  _.each(row, function(value, metric) {
    aggregate[metric] = aggregate[metric] || 0;
    aggregate[metric] += value;
  });
  return aggregate;
}, {});
```

But really feel this can be done much cleaner with Underscore or Lodash functional programming. Any ideas?

Comment: what you've got looks pretty clean to me

Comment: Just for fun with modern ES: [babel/repl](http://tinyurl.com/owd88xs) Ugly though

Comment: Your data is in format of **Array of objects**. So this is a case of m X n. Your solution can be modified as  
_.reduce(function(row, aggregate) {  
  _.each(row, function(value, metric) {  
    aggregate[metric] += aggregate[metric] ? value || 0;  
  });  
  return aggregate;  
}, {});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it cleanly with vanilla javascript:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(totals, v) {
    totals.metric1 += v.metric1;
    totals.metric2 += v.metric2;
    return totals;
}, {metric1: 0, metric2: 0});
```

Edit: If the metric names aren't known until runtime, your solution works fine. Here is another solution using `_.merge`:

```
var result = _.merge.apply(null, [{}].concat(data).concat(function(total, v) {
  return (total || 0) + v;
}));
```

Or if you're using ES6:

```
var result = _.merge({}, ...data, (total=0, v) => {
  return total + v;
});
```

Comment: I'm sure `metric1` are not known statically

Comment: @zerkms I'm not so sure about that, but I guess that's for djechlin to let us know. I've updated my answer with another solution for that case.

Comment: "I'm not so sure about that" --- just check their code.

Comment: @zerkms The code doesn't state whether or not the keys are known statically. He may just be trying to simplify adding additional metrics.

Comment: The code states explicitly that keys are not known. If they were known and it was the case - the code would not have a nested loop.